# Efficient memory usage in python

Tags: python, memory-management, matplotlib, pyodbc

I wrote a Python script using pyodbc to transfer data from an excel sheet into ms access and also using matplotlib to use some of the data in the excel sheet to create plots and save them to a folder. When I ran the script, it did what I expected it to do ; however, I was monitoring it with task manager and it ended up using over 1500 MB of RAM!

I don't even understand how that is possible. It created 560 images but the total size of those images was only 17 MB. The excel sheet is 8.5 MB. I understand that maybe you can't tell me exactly what the problem is without seeing all my code (I don't know exactly what the problem is so I would just have to post the whole thing and I don't think it is reasonable to ask you to read my entire code) but some general guidelines would suffice.

Thanks.

**Update**

I did just as @HYRY suggested and split my code up. I ran the script first with only the matplotlib functions and then afterwards without them. As those who have commented so far have suspected, the memory hog is from the matplotlib functions. Now that we have narrowed it down I will post some of my code. Note that the code below executes in two for loops. The inner for loop will always execute four times while the outer for loop executes however many times is necessary.

```
#Plot waveform and then relative harmonic orders on a bar graph.
#Remember that table is the sheet name which is named after the ExperimentID
cursorEx.execute('select ['+phase+' Time] from ['+table+']')
Time = cursorEx.fetchall()                   
cursorEx.execute('select ['+phase+' Waveform] from ['+table+']')
Current = np.asanyarray(cursorEx.fetchall())                                                               
experiment = table[ :-1]                
plt.figure()
#A scale needs to be added to the primary current values
if line == 'P':
    ratioCurrent = Current / 62.5
    plt.plot(Time, ratioCurrent)
else:
    plt.plot(Time, Current)
plt.title(phaseTitle)
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Current (A)')
plt.savefig(os.getcwd()+'\\HarmonicsGraph\\'+line+'H'+experiment+'.png')

cursorEx.execute('select ['+phase+' Order] from ['+table+']')
cursorEx.fetchone() #the first row is zero
order = cursorEx.fetchmany(51)
cursorEx.execute('select ['+phase+' Harmonics] from ['+table+']')
cursorEx.fetchone()
percentage = np.asanyarray(cursorEx.fetchmany(51))

intOrder = np.arange(1, len(order) + 1, 1)  
plt.figure()                
plt.bar(intOrder, percentage, width = 0.35, color = 'g')                
plt.title(orderTitle)
plt.xlabel('Harmonic Order')
plt.ylabel('Percentage')
plt.axis([1, 51, 0, 100])
plt.savefig(os.getcwd()+'\\HarmonicsGraph\\'+line+'O'+experiment+'.png')
```

Comment: So you need to split your code and find which part is using the memory. I think you can test the matplotlib part first, comment out all the matplotlib code, and see memory useage.

Comment: Well, one obvious place to look is at the images.  Just because they are only 17MB when saved compressed (assuming you are using JPEG or PNG and not BMP), when expanded in memory to a full depth pixel array, they will be much larger.  If you aren't releasing or reusing the resources after creating each one, you could quickly chew through memory.

Comment: @HYRY I will do just that when I get a chance, likely tomorrow. sr2222, the images are PNGs and I always thought that PNGs were uncompressed. Anyway, I guess I will see when I do what HYRY told me to do.

Comment: @Jslick pngs are losslessly compressed ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics)), in contrast to jpegs which are lossy.

Comment: also, as a note, imshow is _not_ memory efficient at all.  You end up with 4+ arrays the size of the image you are plotting (which are all floats, which may be 64bits).  Once it is rastered down and converted to 3 8bit ints per pixel, it will get a lot smaller, even without compression.

Comment: @HYRY I did just as you suggested. My memory problems are from the matplotlib code. I have updated my question. Anyone have any suggestions based on my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a cleanup portion in your code, but I'd be willing to bet that the issue is that you are not calling

```
plt.close()
```

after you are finished with each plot.  Add that one line after you are done with each figure and see if it helps.

Comment: Ahh. Such a simple solution. Not only did it help, but my script executed much more quickly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think that plt.close() is a very hard solution when you will do more than one plot in your script. A lot of times, if you keep the figure reference, you can do all the work on them, calling before:

```
plt.clf()
```

you will see how your code is faster (is not the same to generate the canvas every time!). Memory leaks are terrible when you call multiple axes o figures without the proper clean!